# Why do we need StaticObjects collection when HttpApplicationState can be handled by HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, application-state, httpapplicationstate

i just read we can access HttpApplicationState  using Application or StaticObjects

I am not clear as why we need two different approach
as all i can see is
Application will help you to add and read in the code level
while using staticobjects we can add it in mark-up of global.asax and read but not update

Is this the only difference or Am I missing some core functionality of static objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [HttpApplicationState.StaticObjects property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.staticobjects.aspx):

> Application objects are defined in the Global.asax file inside the `<object runat="server" scope="Application"> </object>` tags.

Comment: In other words, there is no good reason to use `StaticObjects`. It's a holdover from classic ASP.

Comment: Hi John Can you brief on this how StaticObjects were used in classic ASP I am not able to figure how it works

Comment: i need this to complete my blog http://www.blog.sidduhussain.com/staticobjects-collection-in-application-state/

Comment: Sorry, but I never used them. I just remember that when ASP.NET first came out, there was a list of ASP.NET features and how they corresponded to Classic ASP features. I seem to recall that StaticObjects was on that list. Keep in mind that Classic ASP did not use codebehind and StaticObjects makes better sense.